# Prove/ Disprove a logical claim

Tags: logic

> Prove/ Disprove: $\Gamma \vDash_v A$ iff $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot A\}$ isn't valid for every structure.

Clarifications:
$$\Gamma \vDash_v A: \forall M (\forall \rho. [|\Gamma|]^M_\rho = t) \to (\forall \rho. [|A|]^M_\rho = t)$$

I'm not sure I'm using the right term, "valid for $M$" but the meaning is:
for every $\rho$: $[|\varphi]^M_\rho = t$.

Now, I think I can disprove one of the iff sides:

$$\Gamma = \{ p,\lnot p\}, A = p \  (\lnot A = \lnot p)$$

So $\Gamma \cup \lnot A = \{p ,\lnot p\}$ isn't valid for any structure $M$, but $Gamma \vDash_v A$, vacuouly.

Is that right? If not, what counter-example could be used here?

Comment: What kind of thing is $v$ and $\rho$, exactly? Different authors use different notations, and you cannot expect that the variable-name conventions you're used to will also tell a reader what is what. Do variables named $A$ and variables named $\varphi$ range over the same things?

Comment: Is your "clarification" supposed to be a definition of $\Gamma \vDash_v A$ with the colon meaning "means, by definition"? The right-hand side doesn't seem to mention $v$ at all.

Comment: Finally, does your claim parse as $$\bigl[\Gamma\vDash_v A\text{ iff }\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}\text{ isn't valid}\bigr]\text{ for every structure}$$ or $$\Gamma\vDash_v A\text{ iff }\Bigl[\bigl[\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}\text{ isn't valid}\bigr]\text{ for every structure}\Bigr]$$ or $$\Gamma\vDash_v A\text{ iff }\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}\text{ isn't }\bigl[\text{valid for every structure}\bigr]$$ The latter two, at least, are both natural interpretations of the English sentence structure, but mean quite different things!

Comment: @HenningMakholm, it's the middle one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I think $v$ is for *valid*. It's not a variable or anything else. Just a symbol attached to the $\vDash$.

Comment: $A$ is a formula (I know $\varphi$ could be more appropriate here). $\rho$ is a function from terms to the domain of the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have confused yourself, because what you have suggested there is not a counterexample: Setting $\Gamma$ to include a contradiction makes *both sides* of the "iff" true.

The claim you're investigating looks fine at first glance, but there's something fishy about it -- namely that $A$ can contain free variables, and it will then always be interpreted under all possible value assignments $\rho$. This means that such an $A$ is really a stand-in for its universal closure. But then going from $A$ to $\neg A$ is a quite troubling operation, because the universal closure of $\neg A$ is not the same as the negation of the universal closure of $A$!

Thus, intuitively I would stay the claim has no right to work, so let's try to construct a counterexample. It will have to be one with one or more free variables, so let's choose the simplest possible example of that: $A\equiv p(x)$.

Now the claim we're trying to **disprove** reads:

> $$ \Gamma \vDash p(x) \iff \bigl[\Gamma\cup\{\neg p(x)\} \text{ is refutable in every }M\bigr] $$

(where, for simplicity I'm saying "refutable" instead of "not valid": $\varphi$ is refutable in $M$ if there is a $\rho$ such that $\varphi$ is false under $M,\rho$).

Now, what made me think there ought to be a counterexample is that I think what *should* have been instead of $\neg p(x)$ would be $\neg(\forall x)p(x)$, which is equivalent to $(\exists x)\neg p(x)$. It is harder for $\neg p(x)$ to be valid than it is for $(\exists x)\neg p(x)$, which means that it is *easier* for $\Gamma\cup\{\neg p(x)\}$ to be *refutable* than it would have been for $\Gamma\cup\{(\exists x)\neg p(x)\}$ (which I claim would have worked). So I'm going to look for a counterexample where the *right-hand side* of the "iff" is true and the left-hand-side is false.

This means that we have to select $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma\cup\{\neg p(x)\}$ is refutable in every structure. In other words, $\Gamma$ must contraduct $(\forall x)\neg p(x)$. The easiest way for $\Gamma$ to contradict that is its negation, which is $(\exists y) p(y)$. (Using $y$ instead of $x$ is just to make it easier to keep things apart).

Thus we have

> **Counterexample:** $\Gamma = \{(\exists y) p(y)\}$ and $A\equiv p(x)$.

Let's check that. $\Gamma \vDash A$ is certainly *not true* -- for example, in the structure $M=\{1,2\}$ with $p_M=\{1\}$, $\Gamma$ is satisfied but $p(x)$ is not universally valid.

But on the other side: $\Gamma\cup\{\neg A\}$ is $\{(\exists y)p(y), \neg p(x)\}$, and that *is* refutable in every $M$. Namely, either $p_M$ is empty -- and then every $\rho$ refutes $(\exists y)p(y)$ in $M$ -- or there is something in $M$ that $p$ is true for, and then this something refutes $\neg p(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this walkthrough-approach!